# Need suggestions to learn MKMapView and UISearchBar. What are all the concepts i need to study ? Where can i learn those concepts?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to do an IPhone application, where i should implement a MKMapView and an UISearchBar.  if i enter the name of a place in the UISearchBox the related places should returned and The Map Annotation have to be carried out once when we touch a place. What are all the concepts i need to study to implement them?  Where can i learn concepts regarding "MKMapView" and related concepts ?

Suggest me some links in your comments please. Pages which explains programmatically And not using Interface Builder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had never implemented both UISearchBar as well as MKMapView . Will this be enough to study?     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/index https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1

Comment: read ios reference, ios user experience concepts, look for tutorials or example project and the most important put together some code and try it out

Comment: @stefan : thanks for the idea, I tried searching but everything is conceptual, Can u share any link which explains programmatically Plz?

Comment: You learn these by googling and reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use Google map SDK. 
Use MapKit.framwork which comes as apples own library. 
If you do not have specific reason to use Google Map iOS sdk better to learn about MapKit.framework. There are pros and cons when we compare both framework. But since you are in initial stage I recommend to use MapKit.framwork.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/

You can learn basics of UISearchBar using following link.

http://programmerstube.com/mobile/objective-c-tutorial/objective-c-iphone-programming-tutorial-uisearchbar

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest some links which does not make use of XIB? I am not supposed to use Xib :(

Answer (score 0):

I have written simple example. Try to use this one.

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  ```
  mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  mapView.delegate = self;
  mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
  mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
  mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  mapView.rotateEnabled = YES;
  // mapView.pitchEnabled = YES;
  [self moveMapViewToLocation:mapView.userLocation.location];
  [self zoomMapViewToLocation:mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
  [self.view addSubview:mapView];
  ```

  }
  -(void)zoomMapViewToLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location
  {
      if(location.longitude <= -180 || location.latitude <= -180)
      {
          return;
      }

  ```
  MKCoordinateRegion region;
  MKCoordinateSpan span;

  span.latitudeDelta = 0.004;
  span.longitudeDelta = 0.004;

  region.span=span;
  region.center=location;

  [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
  [mapView regionThatFits:region];
  ```

  }

  -(void)moveMapViewToLocation:(CLLocation*)location
  {
      MKCoordinateRegion region;

  ```
  region.span = mapView.region.span;
  region.center = location.coordinate;

  [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
  [mapView regionThatFits:region];
  ```

  }

  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:    (CLAuthorizationStatus)status
    {

  }

  -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
  {
      [self zoomMapViewToLocation:userLocation.coordinate];
  }

  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
    {
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views)
    {
        if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation)
        {
            [self zoomMapViewToLocation:mv.userLocation.location.coordinate];
       }
    }
    }
  - (void)onGestureEventFire:(id)sender
    {
    if(mapView.mapType == MKMapTypeStandard)
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    else
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }
    @end